# Express $1+2\cos a$ as a product

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a problem that involved turning $1+2\cos(a)$ into a product of two or more expressions.

I tried using every possible trigonometric identity to solve it, but I ended up nowhere. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You could write this as $2\left(\tfrac12+\cos a\right)$, observe that $\tfrac12$ is the cosine of a reasonably-nice angle, and then apply an appropriate sum-to-product identity.

Comment: What was the problem that you were working on? As of right now, the information in the question is too limited to fully answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$2\cos^2 (a/2) = 1+\cos(a)$.

Therefore,

$1+2\cos(a) = 4\cos^2 \frac a2 -1 = \left(2\cos\frac a2-1\right)\left(2\cos\frac a2+1\right)$.

Does it work for you?

Comment: $2$ not $\sqrt 2$ in the last expression.

Comment: $1+2\cos(a) = 4\cos^2 (a/2) -1 = (2\cos(a/2)-1)(2\cos(a/2)+1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=2\cos(a)+1$

Factoring out a 2 we get,

$E=2[\cos(a)+\frac{1}{2}]$

We know $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore,

$E=2[\cos(a)+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})]$

We know $\cos(A)+\cos(B) =2\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$

By applying it here we get,

$\cos(a)+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=
 2\cos(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6})$

Substituting this in E we get,

$E=4\cos(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6})$

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$1+2\cos a = 2(\cos a + \cos\frac\pi3)= 4\cos\left(\frac a2 -\frac\pi6\right)\cos\left(\frac a2 +\frac\pi6\right)
$$